# Drupal 7 .install files

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

Is there a way I can get a MODULE.install to use code in other files, presumably something analogous to the files[] = command in MODULE.info?  I assume that I can use a require statement, but this seems to be an anti-Drupal way of doing things.

Comment: Use [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) inside functions, `require_once` if you're including in the global scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clive's comment worked for me as an answer.

> Use [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) inside functions, require_once if you're
>   including in the global scope – Clive

I used module_load_include() in a function; I did not try require_once().  Based on the module_load_include() code, the following should work:

```
require DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $my_module_name) . "/$my_file_name";
```